# How to use animation layers Unity 2d ?How do I make the animation of the sprites show together?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to make an animation of the attack in all states. I already separated all the animations by legs and body parts. The problem is that it only shows the layer that has the maximum weight (For example, the body has the most weight, then it only shows the body itself, without the other parts. And if two sprites have the same weight, then it only shows the layer that is lower). How do I make the animation of the sprites show together?

Answer (score 0):

easily use adictive in non-animation layer setting + Use Sync.
have some practice and you will see the results that you want.
Also you can add sync layers as many as you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).